# how to Change a GET method URL to clean URL in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, clean-url, get-method

This is an URL that created by `GET` method in `php` to send `DATA` parameter to  `archives.html` page:

```
http://127.0.0.1/archives.html?option=com_archive&date=16-2-2014
```

Is there any way to clean this URL?

I want to do something like this (and I can send parameter too!)

```
http://127.0.0.1/archives.html/16-2-2014
```

### Can I do that by mod_rewrite?

(I am developing a component on joomla3)

Comment: "can I do that by mod_rewrite?"  Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1/?option=com_archive&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1?option=com_archive&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R]` as your first rule

Comment: also I tried this: RewriteRule http://127.0.0.1/archives.html?option=com_archive&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R] ... no happen!

Comment: You have to make sure this is your very first URL in root .htaccess and the URL you should use is this: `http://127.0.0.1/archives.html/16-2-2014` for testing.

Comment: thanks. your last code do not work...but I changed it to these: RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ http://127.0.0.1/archives.html/?option=com_archives&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
  ...now it works...can u tell me why?

Comment: Ah I had one slash missing after `$1` see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /archives.html?option=com_archive&date=$1 [L]
```

This htaccess would do this job for you
by url i assume this is joomla

this doc might help you

[http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs_on_Apache](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs_on_Apache)

Comment: thanks for the answer....

but non of method do not work.

I enabled mod_rewrite and  .htaccess before...and active all native joomla sef.

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /archives.html?option=com_archive&date=$1 [L]

(I wana send a parameter from homepage to archives.html page.)
but I get a 500 error for all pages!(include home page)

Comment: [Link Here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_check_if_mod_rewrite_is_enabled_on_your_server)

 <- Check this url and check if mod rewrite is enabled

Comment: [Joomla 500 Internal Error](http://www.joomace.net/support/docs/acesef/faq/modifying-your-joomla-htaccess-file-500-internal-server-error) hope at least this will help you

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in PHP:

```
$original_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/archives.html?option=com_archive&date=16-2-2014';
$new_url = explode('?', $original_url);
$clean_url = $new_url[0];
```

Comment: thanks...the code

just clen the URL to 127.0..0.1 So how can I send parameter to archive.html?